# How do I create an edge application on Azion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I want to use the azion's edge service to upload my project in react (image below)
[Click to see attachment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaMhm.png)

But i don't know hot to use the plataform, can somebody help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** You need to create an Edge Application in the products menu (on the left), this will be your central application and all later settings (cdn, waf, edge functions...) will be applied to it. Of course, you will need to configure a domain for this edge application (custom or automatically generated by the platform).

**Second:** You can't create an edge function react directly in the edge functions panel, that's because the project needs to be built to run on Azion's edge service. For that you will need to use the Azion CLI, found in this link: https://www.azion.com/en/documentation/products/CLI

This CLI allows you to create, build and publish React project (next.js and flareact are currently available) on the edge via command line.

You can see the next.js documentation here https://www.azion.com/en/documentation/use-cases/nextjs-on-azion-platform and flareact (jamstack) here https://www.azion.com/en/documentation/use-cases/jamstack-using-flareact

After that you just need to configure your edge application to execute the function you just created... and welcome to the edge.